# Correct usage of beide and sowohl in German

Tags: word-usage

When to use *beide,* and when to use *sowohl*? I am aware that both of these words mean the same - "both".

Can you provide few examples explaining the usage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are wrong. The word *»sowohl«* does not mean *both*. It means *"as well"* in the construction *"as well as"*, and always comes together with *»als auch«* (which is the second *"as"* in the same construction):

1. > Er spricht **sowohl** Deutsch **als auch** Englisch.
   >   He speaks German **as well as** English.

Compare it with this construction, which is different, but expresses the same meaning:

2. > Es spricht **beides,** Deutsch und Englisch.
   >   He speaks **both,** German and English.

The first construction (**sowohl ... als auch**) is much more common in German than the second, while in English you use more often the second one.  In fact in German the first appearances of the second version was bad translations from Englisch texts. This construction was not usual in German some decades ago and still is bad style.

But since both sentences mean the same, you normally change the construction when you translate:

3. > Er spricht **sowohl** Deutsch **als auch** Englisch.
   >   He speaks **both,** German and English.

But this does not mean, that *sowohl* in any manner can be identified with *both*. The two grammatical constructions in example 3 do not match, so you can't compare single words out of it.

In German you normally use *both* only to talk about two things that build a pair, i.e. that belong together.

> Hast du meinen linken Schuh gesehen? Gestern waren noch **beide** in der Garderobe, aber heute ist nur mehr der rechte da.
>   Did you see my left shoe? Yesterday **both of them** was in the cloakroom, but today only the right one is here.

Comment: "He speaks both, German and English." - I think this should be "He speaks both German and English.", without the comma. In English, the construction "both ... and ..." has the same meaning as "sowohl ... als auch ...".

Comment: *He speaks German as well as English*: Könnte auch »Er spricht Deutsch so gut wie Englisch« heißen.

Comment: @Philipp: Ja, aber nur in diesem Kontext. z.B. bei »He visited Germany as well as England« geht das nicht.

Comment: This answer (that gets everything right about the German side of the topic!) should really be corrected. At least, it should be pointed out that the grammatical constructions in "Er spricht **sowohl** Deutsch **als auch** Englisch." and "He speaks **both** German **and** English." match precisely.

Comment: Wo sagt man denn "nur mehr"? Ich kenne nur "nur noch".

Comment: @infinitezero: Zumindest dort wo ich leben, also in Österreich. z.B. [nur mehr bis Jahresende](https://diepresse.com/home/panorama/wien/5534982/Bundesheer-bewacht-Botschaften-nur-mehr-bis-Jahresende) oder [nur mehr 18,5 km/h](https://derstandard.at/2000091981784/von-E-Sccoter-Geschwindigkeit-wird-automatisch-gedrosselt) oder [nur mehr 325 Euro](https://kontrast.at/lehrlinge-ausbildungsgeld-halbiert/)

Comment: @infinitezero Das kann man aber auch in Deutschland sagen. Für mich wirkt es eher schriftsprachlich, man kann es aber auch in (Nord)Deutschland sagen. Vielleicht ist es in anderen Teilen Deutschlands verbreiteter.

Answer (score 4):

You need a grammar book besides your dictionary. And a good text book which shows you the differences by example:

> Er kannte **beide** Wörter.
>
> Er kannte **sowohl** das eine Wort **als auch** das andere.

*Beide* is a number word meaning *all two of them*. (Same as English *both*.) In contrary *sowohl* is a conjuction which is almost always paired with *als auch*.

---

The negation is as follows:

> Er kannte **keines der beiden** Wörter.
>
> Er kannte **weder** das eine Wort **noch** das andere.

Comment: "Same as English both." - it seems the OP's source of confusion is that in English, "both" can be used in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

You are absolutely right: Depending on the context, **both** translates to either **beide** or **sowohl**.

The former is used to refer to two things (people, objects, concepts, whatever) that are described elsewhere (i.e. at least in a separate subordinate clause). For example:

- "A and B do something. **Both** ..." = "A und B tun etwas. **Beide** ..."
- "X and Y are countries in Asia. **Both countries** ..." = "X und Y sind Länder in Asien. **Beide Länder** ..."

The latter is only the case in a special construction that emphasizes that both out of two items are meant, namely

- "**both** A **and** B" = "**sowohl** A **als auch** B"

The German word *beide* cannot be used in this sense.

---

With the above said, there are a few noteworthy differences between English and German:

- *beide* can stand for itself, whereas English sometimes tends to expand the phrase to *both of them*. A phrasing like "beide von ihnen" or "beide davon" is unidiomatic.
- On the other hand, the plural pronoun is sometimes added for clarification: *wir beide*, *ihr beide*, *sie beide* = *both of us*, *both of you*, *both of them*.
- *beide* can be used with a definite article, *die beiden*, where it rather matches *the two [people, ...]* in English. This form can also be combined with "wir" and "ihr". While "ihr beide" emphasizes that the two addressed people are both included in whatever is currently discussed like with the English "both of you", "ihr beiden" is more like a generic placeholder to avoid a more definite term such as "ihr Kinder" or "ihr Freunde".
- Lastly, while "both" can only ever refer to two things, "sowohl" can also introduce a longer list. While you may not want to stretch it too far, it is perfectly fine to highlight the inclusion of, for example, three things by saying "**sowohl** A **als auch** B **als auch** C".

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Good detailed explanation. Upvoted.